# Add SpecFlow tests to .NET Core project in VSCode

Tags: linux, .net-core, specflow

I've created a .NET Core project and I'm using VSCode on Linux. I installed SpecFlow with `dotnet add package SpecFlow` but I don't think there is IDE integration yet. Can I use the SpecFlow nuget package from the command line to create a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecFlow 3.0 will have .NET Core support. A preview is currently available.

See blog post: https://specflow.org/2018/specflow-3-public-preview-now-available/

To generate the code-behind files we are using the MSBuild generation always for .NET Core. https://specflow.org/2019/generating-code-behind-files-using-msbuild/

Examples can be found here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/NETCore%20Examples

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid but you can't use specflow through command line on linux :(
link on [GitHub](https://github.com/stajs/SpecFlow.NetCore/issues/53) source project.